# Having trouble importing RLGlue: "No module named 'rlglue.rl_glue'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, reinforcement-learning, python-install

I was going through an Reinforcement Learning Course and wanted to try running the code locally. I installed RLGlue with `pip install rlglue` from [here](https://pypi.org/project/rlglue/)

But then when trying to run the code:

```
from rlglue.rl_glue import RLGlue
import main_agent
import ten_arm_env
import test_env
```

Received this error message:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rlglue.rl_glue'`

Any idea on how to fix that to import the module?

Answer (score 1):

I use this as work-around, add this file to your project.

https://gist.github.com/niektuytel/eab1117070454042b11e5e5c026dd3fb